# Trigger my shell script which is available in remote server using Phpseclib

Tags: php, shell, wget, phpseclib

I am very much new with Phpseclib, and I am trying to sh/execute shell script available on my remote server using Phpseclib

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'lib/phpseclib1.0.5');
include('lib/phpseclib1.0.5/Net/SSH2.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);
include_once ("admin/model/JobDAO.php");
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.11.68');
if (!$ssh->login('amit', 'password')) {
exit('Login Failed');
}
$ssh->setTimeout(1000);
$deployment_script="./InstallJava-Final.sh";
$ssh->exec(
    $deployment_script, function ($str) {
        echo $str;
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    });

?>
```

Above PHP code trigger my shell script **InstallJava-Final.sh** which is available in the remote server and show the output on the browser that It's downloading java from oracle website using wget but few second later the process Stopped.

[image: browser output]

My remote script should run properly without interruption/stop with **root user**

Comment: Worked fine for me: http://pastebin.com/GCKT1c9B Maybe try commenting out the echo in the anonymous function and enabling real-time logging by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3)` at the top. Once it hangs grab the output and then post it on pastebin.com and then post the link on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Not working as expected. Using the Script I am downloading Java from oracle website but script is not downloading completely.Click on the below link and check the difference in downloading java size   https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJd7O.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soxda.jpg

Comment: And what is the URL you are using to download that file? Maybe you could post your `InstallJava-Final.sh`? And also, maybe you could post your log files, as I asked?